# C++ Qt cannot read the whole text file

Tags: c++, qt, file, text, buffer

I'm writing a tool for private use. The problem is that Qt cannot read a text file containing [all contents published here](http://pastebin.com/shYSgihU).

It only reads [this](http://pastebin.com/HgRbbSpA)
The three points were pasted by Qt.

My code for reading the file is following

```
QFile file;
file.setFileName(m_filename);
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    return;

QTextStream in(&file);

while (!in.atEnd()) {
    m_fileContents += in.readLine();
}
file.close();
```

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: I tried the std libs from c++. Even these will only read ~895 chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QFile file;
file.setFileName(m_filename);
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    return;

m_fileContents = file.readAll();
```

Comment: whats your file size? =)

Comment: Well, wait. The file size is 895 Bytes, but something's wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code on my own computer with your data and it works well.
If you're using an IDE, maybe it does not display all the text of your final string and this is why you have three dot at the end of your sample.

Also as evilruff suggest you can use QFile::readAll method directly.